# How to set CustomFrame on iCarousel in iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I want to set the frame of iCarousel according to my need. First it shows in the middle of the simulator but i tried my code now it is showing at the top of the simulator.

I am trying this code:

```
// Try to add custom view for setting height and width of iCarousel

UIView *Carasouel_Customview = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, -245, 768, 245)];
[self.view addSubview:Carasouel_Customview];


// Initialize and configure the carousel

//carousel = [[iCarousel alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
carousel = [[iCarousel alloc] initWithFrame:Carasouel_Customview.bounds];
//carousel = [[iCarousel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 200, 179, 245)];
carousel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth |    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
carousel.type = iCarouselTypeRotary;
carousel.dataSource = self;
carousel.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:carousel];
```

Any hints from experts would be very welcome.

Comment: What do you mean by "in the middle of the simulator" and "at the top of the simulator". Can you provide us some screenshots? I really can not understand what do you expect and what do you get instead?

Comment: @Bing exactly sir, The view not set according to the co-ordinates i used -245 so it should be show on  -245 but not it takes the co-oedinates from 0(Y=0), if I give Y co-ordinate 400 even if it start from Y=0.

Comment: @Mert Sir top of the simulator means it start from y=0 and i give the yCoordinate -245 , if I give Ycoordinate 510 (middle height of simulator) even if it start from Y=0.

Comment: You use bounds instead of frame, thats why it is 0. Bounds is relative to is its self. I would recommend you to read from apple docs the differences between frame and bounds

Comment: @Mert Ok Sir, I will read, Thanks allot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting y-coordinate `-245` to `Carasouel_Customview` and then setting `carousel.frame` with `Carasouel_Customview.bounds` - here y-coordinate is 0.

You are adding `carousel` to `self.view`, not `Carasouel_Customview` - so what do you expect?

Solution:
Add `carousel` as subview to `Carasouel_Customview` or set `carousel.frame` with custom values.

Answer (score 3):

```
self.carousel = [[iCarousel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 200.0, 150.0)];
self.carousel.delegate = self;
self.carousel.dataSource = self;
self.carousel.type = iCarouselTypeLinear;

self.carousel.clipsToBounds = YES; //This is main point

[self.view addSubview:self.carousel];
```

When we set customFrame to [iCarousel](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel) we get its width of fullScreen. So just set its **clipsToBounds** property `YES` :)

Comment: "self.carousel.clipsToBounds = YES;"  helps me) Thnx)

Comment: Loved your answer buddy  'clipsToBounds = YES; ' saved my day.